# check data before-after mariadb upgrade

Tags: mariadb, upgrade

I plan to upgrade from
10.1.2
to
10.11.6
and the upgrade with a test db shows success.

But i wanted to check for any differences and tried:

1. diff of `mysqldump`
2. diff of `mysqldump --no-data` (structure only)
3. table and index sizes
4. `CHECKSUM TABLE`

before and after the upgrade.

1. The mysqldump makes no sense. Too large and the dump format changes on higher versions (line breaks ect).
2. The structure only dump makes sense.
   I could see some changes that are nice to know:
   Examples:

```
-) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=852701 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
+) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=852701 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3 COLLATE=utf8mb3_general_ci;

-  `breakpoint` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
+  `breakpoint` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
```

3. The table and index size comparison seems to make sense and stays the same.
   The query i use:

```
SELECT table_schema as                                        `Database`,
       table_name   AS                                        `Table`,
       round(((data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024), 2) `Size in MB`,
       round((data_length / 1024 / 1024), 2)                  `Data in MB`,
       round((index_length / 1024 / 1024), 2)                 `Index in MB`
FROM information_schema.TABLES
WHERE information_schema.TABLES.TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE()
ORDER BY (data_length + index_length) DESC, `Table` ASC;
```

4. The `CHECKSUM TABLE` works, but the checksum is different on some tables. I guess this because of structural changes - all those tables with structured changes have a different checksum.

That is why im here. **How do i check the data after an upgrade.**
And|or do|can i actually?

Comment: You should have saved key query outputs (row counts, distinct values, totals) from the old version per table and rerun the same queries after the upgrade and compare results.

Comment: what is your concern?  assuming your data isn't corrupt in the first place, an upgrade isn't going to change anything.  when upgrading, the main worry is that your queries still function, and function performantly, not anything about the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the `mariadb-dump` of the newer MariaDB against the old data. Its untested but will be consistent with new lines and potentially less differences.

`mariadb-check --extended` is one way to ensure all tables are in a fully good state.

Another way is using [pt-table-sync](https://docs.percona.com/percona-toolkit/pt-table-sync.html)

```
pt-table-sync --execute --verbose --databases my_database_name h=my_host_1,u=my_user_1,p=my_pass_1 h=my_host_2,u=my_user_2,p=my_pass_2
```

Will ensure data consistency and display differences.

Note: a `--dry-run` as an argument won't actually perform comparison.

Comment: The dry run seem to not compare data (the tool outputs such a note if you run it in dry run mode).
But running with `--execute` compares, updates and shows the changes. The exit codes makes it even better.
`pt-table-sync --execute --verbose --databases my_database_name h=my_host_1,u=my_user_1,p=my_pass_1 h=my_host_2,u=my_user_2,p=my_pass_2`
Thank you =)

Comment: Ah, thank you. It has been a few years since I've used it. updated Answer. Happy migration, hope it goes well. And please report bugs. I assume you've run `mariadb-upgrade` too.

Comment: You should re-add the link to the `pt-table-sync` tool. Also you adde my example command that has NO dry run flag, so you should have added a warning.

Comment: Note: after a mariadb upgrade i get errors with `pr-table-sync` one some mariadb versions: `Failed to make checksum queries: CRC32 never needs the BIT_XOR optimization at /usr/bin/pt-table-sync line 4818.`. I dont kow why the CRC32 hash funktion does not work, but if i use the option `--function="MD5"` (or SHA1) it works.